# Can a Swift Package import a executableTarget?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

When I call the `main()` function of the imported executableTarget, there are errors:

> Undefined symbol:
>
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is that impossible for a executable target depends on another executable target in the same package?